# changing namespace of current python script (class with module name)

Tags: python, import, namespaces

i have a 2.6 python script and library in the following directory structure:

```
+ bin
\- foo.py
+ lib
\+ foo
 \- bar.py
```

i would like users to run `bin/foo.py` to instantiate the classes within `lib/foo.py`. to achieve this, in my `bin/foo.py` script i have the following code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import foo
klass = foo.bar.Klass()
```

however, this results in:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

ie it thinks that `foo` is itself rather than the library `foo` - renaming `bin/foo.py` to `bin/foo-script.py` works as expected.

is there a way i can keep the `bin/foo.py` script and import `lib/foo.py`?

Comment: Have you tried `import foo as bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current directory is on the path by default, so you need to remove that before you import the other `foo` module:

```
import sys
sys.path = [dir for dir in sys.path if dir != '']
```

Alternatively, prepend the `lib` directory so that it takes precedence:

```
import sys
sys.path = ['../lib'] + sys.path
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just write import foo, it will definitely load the foo module in the current scope. Assuming lib and foo as packages, won't you need to write something like this in order to make it work?

```
import lib.foo.bar as foobar
klass = foobar.Klass()
```